# customize wordpress admin panel hiding features

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to hide current theme features from worpress admin panel
and i am using this code in function.php

```
 function remove_menus(){
 remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
 remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );                    //Jetpack*
 //  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
 //  remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
 //  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages
 remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
 //  remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings
 remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=themify' );    //swpakistan

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

but the theme contain function.php has below code to prevent me for doing this,

```
$theme_includes = apply_filters( 'themify_theme_includes',
array(  'themify/themify-database.php',
                        'themify/class-themify-config.php',
                        'themify/themify-utils.php',
                        'themify/themify-config.php',
                        'themify/themify-modules.php',
                        'theme-options.php',
                        'theme-modules.php',
                        'theme-functions.php',
                        'custom-modules.php',
                        'custom-functions.php',
                        'theme-class.php',
                        'themify/themify-widgets.php' ));

foreach ( $theme_includes as $include ) { locate_template( $include, true ); }
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: Have you tried a Child Theme - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes - please note the section Using functions.php.

Comment: no, did not tried child theme, but even if i use, the admin panel will be accessible by admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a plugin that give you permissions to set to each user role and restrict access to certain sections of the backend

Comment: master admin can bypass that. and in cpanel it will be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the filter? 
Something like : **remove_filter( 'hook_name', 'themify_theme_includes' );**

Comment: Looks more like a comment.

Comment: Jakiboy, just tried it, and it serves,
but when i access my site it shows blank page, with no errors.

Comment: Enable the WP_DEBUG option in wp-config.php by setting it to True, by this way you can see the error. you have to set a valid {**hook_name**}